# Bash ~ Access directory that may change, from script within sub-directories of directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, directory

I'm a bit new to bash and its workings but I am wondering is there anyway in bash to access a directory that may change in its address due to where the user installs it in bash. (This happens all the time, so there must be)

For example:
I have a program that has the directory of `../program-directory/..`

But then the user downloads the program files in `/extra-directory/`creating a situation where we have `/extradirectory/program-directory`

Then I have a bash script that runs in `../program-directory/script-directory/script/example.bash`

I would then like to `grep -rnw 'sample text' /program-directory` from the `example.bash` script

Is there any simple way in one line I can grep in `program-directory` without the hassle of where the user installed this program

FYI, I have looked at [Can a Bash script tell which directory it is stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-which-directory-it-is-stored-in) but I need to grep in `../program-directory` from a script called in a sub-directory of `../program-directory`

Comment: This is a very confusing description, and I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying (in your last line) that you need to remember a directory, to be able to switch back to it later? If so, `$OLDPWD` saves the prior value of `$PWD`. But it might be better for you to post some code to show what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, and where it fails if you got that far.

Comment: Do you just want a relative path, as in `grep -rnw 'sample text' ../..`?

Comment: Apologies that last line I wrote is stupid, I simply just want to access ../program-directory with the example.bash script

Comment: @ccarton Yes I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is in  `/some/example/dir/program-directory/script-directory/script/example.bash` and you want to run `grep` on the file `/some/example/dir/program-directory/sample.txt` then you write in bash code:

```
main() {
    local DIR="$(dirname "$0")"
    local DIR="$(cd "${DIR}" && pwd)"
    cd "${DIR}"
    grep 'search term' -- ../../sample.txt
}
```

there are many variants of the code above with the same meaning or slightly altered meaning. This code is written for clarity and correct handling of directory names with spaces and special characters. This code ignores the currend working directory on purpose (which is what you wanted as far as I can tell).